# QWebView can't render unicode font on windows xp

Tags: qt, webview, fonts, font-face, render

I have problem with QWebView. I wrote small app which renders web application. I have font(unicode) problem. On my windows 7 it renders correct font, but on windows xp(virtual machine) doesn't render font.

this is my code:

```
//QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/files/acadnusx.ttf");

QFontDatabase database;
foreach (const QString &family, database.families()) {
    qDebug() << family;
}

QWebSettings *settings = ui->webView->settings();
//settings->clearMemoryCaches();
//settings->setFontFamily(QWebSettings::StandardFont, "acadnusx");
//settings->setFontSize(QWebSettings::DefaultFontSize, 12);
settings->setDefaultTextEncoding("utf-8");
```

I listed QFontDatabase fonts and On Windows xp some fonts are missing.
How my question is: how detect which fonts uses web view on my windows xp and than add that font to QFontDatabase to render this font in windows xp(or another platform)